# How to toggle class of closest element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below code to click on an image within the .process  class and when clicked the .process-info with toggle class of .process--shown.

This code works; however, it will toggle the class of process--shown for all elements on the page with the class of .process-info;

I only want the element clicked on to acitivate

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".process .process--img").click(function(){
  $(".process .process--info").toggleClass("process--shown") 
});    
  $(".process .process--info").click(function(){
    $(".process .process--info").toggleClass("process--shown") 
  });    
});
```

Comment: inside the click event chnage the selector from $(".process .process--info") to $(this)

Comment: There is a jQuery selector called `closest`...

Comment: Show relevant html structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` current element context to traverse up to common parent using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(".process .process--img").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".process").find(".process--info").toggleClass("process--shown")
});
```

Comment: This is perfect

Thanks so much !

Comment: Would it be possible to add an event that removes the class shown if it is present in the Dom if an element is clicked and shown is going to be toggled to remove it from other elements